# Team Explorer work item UI is too wide

Tags: tfs, workitem, team-explorer

Is there any way to get the work item query results preview pane to auto-size its width?  It is very often "too wide", with the controls being way too wide for their content.  Here's an example--why do I have to have horizontal scrolling?  Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

(When one opens a single work item, the width is streched appropriately. This is the behavior I want for the above query results preview.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite is opening work items when checking code in.  If you open the work item from the check in window, close it, and open it again, then the spacing starts doubling.  Every time you reopen it the spacing just gets bigger.

It's a bug.  Hopefully 2010 fixes this.